# Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-dom

Hi I know this type of question has been asked quite a few times but I couldn't get the answer.

I am trying to write a React hello world example. I have only two files one app.jsx and another homepage.jsx. I am using webpack to bundle the files.

But when I run the code I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`

My homepage.jsx looks like this

```
"use strict";

var React = require('react');

var Home = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div className="jumbotron">                
                <h1> Hello World</h1> 
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Home;
```

My app.js looks like this

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Home = require('./components/homePage');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Home/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

In browser it throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined` at line 7 i.e where I am requiring homepage.

But when I add var React = require('react') in app.jsx it works fine.

I don't understand this. I have included react in homepage.jsx where I am making use of it. In app.jsx I only require react-dom becuase I don't use React. Then why it is giving error in app.jsx.

Pls help!!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Change your `app.js` to this

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Home = require('./components/homePage');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Home/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

JSX is transformed into `React.createElement()` calls, thus React is required in scope. So yes, you are using `React` in `app.js`.
Get used to import it whenever you use JSX or direct `React.*` calls.

Comment: I'm a bit new to this stuff but any chance you could explain why the `require('react-dom')' does not pull in React?

Comment: `react-dom` is only "renderer" which converts React elements into DOM nodes/elements. Take a look at React Native, which does not require `react-dom` since it has its own renderer which converts React elements into native elements depending on platform. In early days, React included code which was extracted into now existing `react-dom`.

Comment: @Andreyco when i use above code, i got this error 
ReferenceError: require is not defined
var React = require('react');
please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: That looks confusing (the need to import React, despite the code not showing it being used and compiling just fine). Is this the only time where you would need to do something like this?

Answer (score 14):

You can have it without require it in your code.

Add to **webpack.config.js**:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    "React": "react",
  }),
],
```

See https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#root