# React.PropTypes is deprecated since React 15.5.0

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am facing an issue where I am trying to import a static component and use it in the parent component. I am getting React undefined error.

Here what I have done
Parent Component

```
import React from 'react';
import TableHeader from 'TableHeader';
import TableRow from 'TableRow';
import UTIL from '../../services/Utils';

export default class Table extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <TableHeader labels={this.props.labels}/>
            <div className="table-body js-filtered-data-wrapper sortable">
                {this.renderTableRows()}
            </div>

        </div>
        )
    }
    renderTableRows() {
        return this.props.teamlist.map((listItem, i) => {
            return (
                <TableRow key={i}
                               data={listItem}
                               labels={this.props.labels}
                />
            )
        });
    }
}
```

in my TableHeader file the code is

```
import { PropTypes } from 'react';

const TableHeader = (props) => {
    let labels = props.labels;
    return (
        <ul className="table-header">
            <li className="table-row header ">
                <div className="player-name">{labels.playername}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    )
}

TableHeader.propTypes = {
    labels : PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default TableHeader;
```

The error I am getting is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at TableHeader (webpack:///./src/components/pro-am/TableHeader.jsx?:13)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341994/uncaught-referenceerror-react-is-not-defined) (TL;DR - any file with JSX in it needs to `import React from "react"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imoprt `React` in the `TableHeader` component too:

> NOTE: With the latest version of `React` the `PropTypes` have been moved
>   to a Separate package(`prop-types`). So import it from there like

```
import React,{ PropTypes } from 'react';

const TableHeader = (props) => {
    let labels = props.labels;
    return (
        <ul className="table-header">
            <li className="table-row header ">
                <div className="player-name">{labels.playername}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    )
}

TableHeader.propTypes = {
    labels : PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default TableHeader;
```

If using v15.5.0 or above use PropTypes from a separate package

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const TableHeader = (props) => {
    let labels = props.labels;
    return (
        <ul className="table-header">
            <li className="table-row header ">
                <div className="player-name">{labels.playername}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    )
}

TableHeader.propTypes = {
    labels : PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default TableHeader;
```

Comment: It will not help as this will generate this error 'Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined'

Comment: I will help, try it

Comment: I am not using the latest version so thats fine. I guess

Comment: Yes that will be ok, just added that as a NOTE

Comment: Glad to have helped, however I agree with you sometimes React will give not so helpful warnings

Comment: Wait for 4 mins :P

Comment: Yes, SO rules :)