# ReactJs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'PropTypes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router v3.2.0 and this is my app.js, error is showing on line router: PropTypes.object in chrome and in edge it shows error as TypeError: Unable to get property 'object' of undefined or null reference at 
class App extends React.Component , btw I am new to react

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  }

  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    routes: PropTypes.element.isRequired
  };

  get content() {
    return (
      <Router
        routes={this.props.routes}
        history={this.props.history} />
    )
  }

  render () {
     return (

       <div className="App">
         <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
          <h2>Welcome to Vavavoom!</h2>
           {this.content}
         </div>
      </div>
     )
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: PropTypes is a separate library now. https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071022/getting-react-not-defined-in-static-component-in-react/44071067#44071067

Comment: That's not helping

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was copying an old example and ran into the same issues. It was saying that there was an error in bootstrap. I installed bootstrap too. > __webpack_require__ C:/Users/WillFilm4Food/Documents/GitHub/test2/webpack/bootstrap:781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why but changing version of `react-router": "^3.2.0` to `react-router": "^3.0.0` and `react-dom": "^16.2.0` to `react-dom": "^15.3.2` solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

First of all, give up on importing `PropTypes from react`. It is deprecated.

Instead,  start using  `import PropTypes from 'prop-types`
The rest should work the way you are using it.

Comment: I added module prop-types and used import PropTypes from 'prop-types' as you said, but it shows this `TypeError: Unable to get property 'func' of undefined or null reference` at `./node_modules/react-router/lib/PropTypes.js`

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using? Can you also show the content inside `routes` props?

Comment: I am using react-router v3.2.0

Comment: And I am following this small tutorial [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/multifactor-authentication-in-your-react-apps)

Comment: Update your `router ` to

```<Router history={this.props.history}>
 {this.props.routes}
</Router>```

Comment: I updated my router in app.js, but it shows same error

Comment: There is something wrong with the way, you are constructing the `routes`. If it is a function, somewhere in the stack you are not importing it properly, Please show the other part of `route`, whichyou are passing as props.

Comment: I pushed my code to [git repository](https://github.com/sathwik77/multifactor-auth-react/tree/master/src) can you please check it